# Needing to add a dynamic job Id to the uri using Guzzle 7

Tags: laravel, async-await, uri, guzzle

Im passing in a job Id that dynamically needs to populate the uri in guzzle 7 here is the client:

```
 $client = new GuzzleHttp\Client([
        'base_uri' => 'https://portal.2nformserver.com/arcgis/rest/services/getLocalRefData/GPServer/Get%20Local%20Reference%20Data/',
       ['headers' => [
           'Accept' =>'application/json'
       ]]
    ]);
```

here is the promise:

```
$promise = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'jobs/', ['query' => [
        "f"=>"json"
    ]]);
```

I am needing to pass in a $jobId variable into the Uri portion of the request. I have not been able to find a way to do this. I was hoping for something as easy as:

```
$promise = $client->requestAsync('GET', 'jobs/{$jobId}', ['query' => [
        "f"=>"json"
    ]]);
```

or to be able to add something to the array I could pass in but have come up with no answers any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: change `'jobs/{$jobId}'` to `"jobs/{$jobId}"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can pass variable to uri using php string format:

```
$promise = $client->requestAsync('GET', "jobs/$jobId", ['query' => [
    "f"=>"json"
]]);
```